# Two python class instances have a reference to each other

Tags: python, class

I am having two python classes, let's call them A and B. A is responsible for handling the receiving and sending of messages of a certain format over the network. B is responsible for interpretation of the messages.

Now a and b are instances of classes A and B respectively. Consider the following scenario:

- a receives a message and calls some method of b for message interpretation
- b processes the message and wants to use some method of a to send a response

To achieve this I constructed two classes that have a reference to each other. This works fine but I would like to ask you if this a design flaw and should be avoided?

For illustration see the following minimal code example:

```
class A:

    def set_b(self, b):
        self.b = b


class B:

    def set_a(self, a):
        self.a = a


if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = A()
    b = B()

    b.set_a(a)
    a.set_b(b)
```

Comment: Its hard to say, It doesn't sound like having B as a separate class gives much value to me

Comment: I would agree with @Sayse, this is not inherently wrong, but I would potentially rethink what you are trying to do. It may be more beneficial to have B as a sub-class of A (assuming it is not used elsewhere).

Comment: Well, when I started working on the project B did not have to give an answer. I am writing several modules and A (i.e. the message handling) always stays the same while B has to be implemented individually. That was the initial reason for having two classes.

Comment: @BrandonM: maybe I could define it as a subclass. The thing is that I have an abstract class (abc.ABCMeta) from which B is derived for each module. That makes sure that the structure of each individual class B for each of the modules stays the same. Maybe I'd have to look into multiple inheritance.

Comment: Arguably, splitting the classes can make sense. If one is concerned with sending and receiving stuff, and the other is concerned with making decisions, it's perfectly fine to keep them separate. Now, instead of `set_a` and `set_b`, I would rename those to `set_sender` and `set_message_handler` for instance. The point being you can replace either without touching the other — and there is value in doing so, otherwise it's just over-engineered.

Comment: Alright, then I'll leave it the way it is as it is also easier to test. I was just a bit concerned about that cross reference and that this would inherently be a design flaw by some software engineering principle. ;) Anyways, thanks all for your inputs.

Comment: Well, yeah if the split between the two objects is well defined, it makes testing easier, as you can test each object separately by providing it with a mock object (test the objects by giving them a dummy sender/message handler that just logs the sends/messages instead of sending/handling them). This enables you to test logic such as "verify that when receiving this message in that circumstances the logic triggers this answers". Independently of the details of how messages and answers are sent and received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPython added cyclic garbage collection some versions ago because cyclic dependencies are common enough to be an issue.  Still, you might be able to not create a cycle by having the methods of `a` that call a method of `b` pass `self` instead of depending on `b` already having a reference to `a`.

If you stick with the cycle, I would make the linkage as automatic as possible.  For instance:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        a.set_b(self)

a = A()
b = B(a)
# Both instances are fully initialized and ready to go.
```

If you forget to pass `a` to `B`, you get an immediate exception.